# MSVC throws "Run-Time Check Failure #2" (corrupted stack) for this use of the overload / std::visit pattern (C++17)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm using the "overload" pattern to make a visitor for a std::variant, defining the methods as lambdas with a generic lambda to provide an empty default method. (Full example code later)

```
// imagine declaration of the overload template + the deduction helper here ...

using Foodstuff = std::variant<Fruit, Vegetable, Meat, Dairy, Fish>;

int things_eaten{0};

auto picky_eater = overload{
    // Eats fruit
    [&things_eaten](const Fruit&) { things_eaten++; },
    // Eats dairy
    [&things_eaten](const Dairy&) {things_eaten++; },

    // Doesn't eat anything else - I need an empty handler for the other foodstuffs
    [](auto) {}
};
```

Then I use this to `std::visit` a vector of foods. Compiling this in either MSVC 2022 (v17.7.6), targetting the C++17 language standard, I get no compiler warnings (at /W3) and the program runs as I expect in the "release" target, but it I change it to debug as it exits the function I get the exception

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'picky_eater'
> was corrupted.

Noting that the other lambdas had a capture and the final generic lambda did not, if I change  that last overload to `[&things_eaten](auto) {}`, that exception goes away.

Furthermore, if I change the language standard to C++20 the original version does not generate that exception.

Is the exception identifying a real problem in the original code, and did C++20 introduce something (maybe the template deduction changes?) that resolves it? Is this a weird bug in MSVC C++17 runtime checks in debug buuilds (I don't have other compilers or analysis tools to compare with).

---

```
#include <variant> 
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// Overload pattern

template <typename... Ts>
struct overload : Ts...
{
    using Ts::operator()...;
};

// Template deduction helper; needed in C++17
template <typename... Ts>
overload(Ts...)->overload<Ts...>;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct Fruit {
    std::string name;
};

struct Vegetable {
    std::string name;
};

struct Meat {
    std::string name;
};

struct Dairy {
    std::string name;
};

struct Fish {
    std::string name;
};

using Foodstuff = std::variant<Fruit, Vegetable, Meat, Dairy, Fish>;
using Meal = std::vector<Foodstuff>;

int main() {
    auto meal = Meal{ Fruit{"Apple"}, Vegetable{"Tomato"}, Meat{"Beef"}, Vegetable{"Potato"}, Dairy{"Yoghurt"} };

    int things_eaten{ 0 };

    auto picky_eater = overload{
        // Eats fruit
        [&things_eaten](const Fruit&) { things_eaten++; },

        // Eats dairy
        [&things_eaten](const Dairy&) { things_eaten++; },

        // Doesn't eat anything else - I need an empty handler for the other foodstuffs

        // If I write the generic lambda this way, MSVC in C++17 langauge standard will
        // give an exception in Debug builds:
        // "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'picky_eater' was corrupted."
        [](auto) {}

        // But if I just add the same capture, even though it's not used, that error goes away?
        // [&things_eaten](auto) {}
    };

    for (const auto& ingredient : meal) {
        std::visit(picky_eater, ingredient);
    }

    std::cout << "I ate " << things_eaten << " things" << std::endl;
    return 0;
    // As the program exits, we get the exception
}
```

Comment: I can reproduce this but only with x86, with x64 it runs fine. You should update the question with that information.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - I get the problem with both x86 and x64

Comment: Simplest version that crashes here (x86 only): https://godbolt.org/z/5afvYxo3c

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the shown code. Compiler bug.

Comment: Side note, you should use `const auto&` in the final empty lambda to be consistent. I don't think it has anything to do with your issue though!

Comment: Similar issue fixed in the past: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Runtime-stack-corruption-using-std::visi/346200

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks correct and can be further simplified to

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded( Ts... )->overloaded<Ts...>;

int main() {
  int i{ 0 };
  auto lambda = overloaded{
    [&i](int) {},
    [](auto) {}
  };
}
```

while preserving stack corruption error in Visual Studio.

I reported it to MS team: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Run-Time-Check-Failure-2---Stack-around/10510860

and based on their repospone it is a real compiler bug, which was first reported back in 2019: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Capturing-lambdas-in-function-object-res/475396